# Building Android 8.0 Kernel on VMM on Ubuntu - Too Many Open Files Error

Tags: gnome, kernel, android

Every time I build Android 8 kernel from source I get a "Too many open files" error at some point and the build fails. I have searched for solutions and tried a lot of stuff but nothing works.

Background:

I am building a custom Android 8 kernel for an industrial tablet. I am not new to this. I have been doing this for a couple of years on a very old PC that is really slow. The old PC ran Ubuntu 18.04 and Gnome and the Android 8 kernel build worked fine every time on that PC.

But my company bought me a hot, new machine to speed-up the builds (Woo-hoo!). The new machine is Dell 7680 with 64-core (128 threads) AMD processor with 64GB of memory.

I installed Ubuntu 22.04.04 LTS and Gnome. Then I installed VMM and created a VM build environment running Ubuntu 18.04 and Gnome, since that matches the old machine. The VMM has 64 threads assigned (out of 128) and 49GB of memory assigned.

Every time I build the  I get a "Too many open files" error at some point. My make command is 'make -j12 dist' so make should only be using 12 cores in theory. I tried 'make dist', which should use a single processor, but it still failed.

I modified /etc/systemd/user.conf and system.conf both to set "DefaultLimitNOFILES=8192" and rebooted. `ulimit -n` now shows 8192. Builds still fail, same error.

After build, `lsof | wc -l` output varies between 60K and 80K open files (varies per run)

`cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` returns `4928093`.
`cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr` returns `7680 0 4928093`. As I understand it, that means there are 7680 files open and the system limit is 4.9M files.

Both of these numbers are much greater than the ulimit of 8192 so I am clearly not understanding something. I gather the ulimit is the file limit *per process* whereas file-max is file limit of the system (file system limit), correct?

For comparison, I rebooted the PC for a fresh system. The Ubuntu 22.04 host `lsof | wc -l` show 60K open files while doing nothing (fresh boot/login). Yowsah!

The I started a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 VMM. `'lsof | wc -l'` shows 60K open files as well, again while doing nothing. Just a fresh login.

Researching this problem I ran across the following suggested by many users:

`lsof | head -1 | awk '{ print "COUNT " $2 " " $1; }' && sudo lsof +c 0 | awk '{ print $2 " " $1; }' | sort -rn | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -20`

The output shows me that the idle machine has 24K files owned by 'JS\x20Helper', which I understand is Gnome.

````
      Output information may be incomplete.
COUNT PID COMMAND
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
  24684 1907 JS\x20Helper
   6171 1907 gnome-shell
   2278 1514 Xorg
    728 1339 snapd
    369 2287 pool
    369 2287 evolution-calen
    363 1907 threaded-ml
    363 1907 llvmpipe-9
    363 1907 llvmpipe-8
    363 1907 llvmpipe-7
    363 1907 llvmpipe-6
    363 1907 llvmpipe-5
    363 1907 llvmpipe-4
    363 1907 llvmpipe-3
    363 1907 llvmpipe-2
    363 1907 llvmpipe-15
    363 1907 llvmpipe-14
    363 1907 llvmpipe-13
    363 1907 llvmpipe-12
    363 1907 llvmpipe-11```

Since Gnome is sucking up so many files I decided to kill Gnome and kick-off build from basic console window. ```<ctrl><alt><F2>``` got me to tty2 (Gnome is on tty1). I killed gwm3 process but the VMM didn't like that. It popped me back to tty1 and restarted Gnome.

I am stumped. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.
````

Comment: Just on a lark, I modified /etc/systemd/system.conf and user.conf to have NOFILES limit of 81920 (increased 10x). After reboot, I started a build with a single processor and it worked. It looks like 8448 files were used in build.

Why are these files not released after the build?